# d3: select a subset of data by key for binding elements

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, bind

I have a nested (2D) JSON array. When binding the second dimension of the array I would like to bind only elements that have an "id"-key, i.e. I would like to ignore the element with the "column" key.

With my current example code I am generating as many children as elements I have. However, I would need need one fewer.

```js
  jsonNodes = [{"id": 0, 
       "table": [{"id": 10}, {"id": 11}, {"id": 12}, 
          {"column": [{"id": "a"}]}]},
             {"id": 1,
       "table": [{"id": 20}, {"id": 21},
          {"column": [{"id": "y"}, {"id": "z"}]}]}
            ];

  // bind svg element
  var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 50)

  // build steps
  var stepG = svgContainer.selectAll("svg")
    .data(jsonNodes)
     
  var stepGenter = stepG.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return "id" + d.id; });

  // append to individual class
  var tableG = stepGenter.selectAll("g")
    .data(function(d, i) { console.log(d.table[i]);
            return d.table; })
    
  var tableGenter = tableG.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return "id" + d.id; });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wouldn’t `.data(d => table.filter(e => e.id))` be sufficient?

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Many thanks